# Rails5, nested form, undefined param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes, accepts-nested-attributes

Huston, we have a problem:

```
class FirstModel 
 has_many :merged_models
 has_many :second_models, :through => :merged_models
end

class SecondModel 
 has_many :merged_models
 has_many :first_models, :through => :merged_models
end

class MergedModel 
 belongs_to :first_model
 belongs_to :second_model
end
```

Form:

```
<%= form_for(first_model) do |f| %>
 <%= f.fields_for :merged_model do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.label :date %>
    <%= ff.date_select :start_date %>
```

Problem:

> Processing by FirstModelsController#create as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"f+D8AaVzM6ahrUyo/nwxISFEleVrXGxo8m30sIiLIe7gvG8J9KfONjuT09j6z3M4Rvw+n3Hm6PMddOtfbgjt5g==",
>   "first_model"=>{"first_name"=>"yyyy", "last_name"=>"yyy",
>   "merged_model"=>{"start_date(1i)"=>"2017", "start_date(2i)"=>"2",
>   "start_date(3i)"=>"28", "second_model_id"=>"1"}}, "commit"=>"Create"}
>   Unpermitted parameter: merged_model Unpermitted parameter:
>   merged_model

First model's controller's strong params:

```
  params.require(:first_model).permit(:first_name, :last_name, merged_models_attributes: [:id, :start_date])
```

First model acccepts nested attributes of merged model:

```
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :merged_models
```

However, after creating a FirstModel, MergedModel does not get created. Tried to create it in form:

```
  <%= f.fields_for :merged_model [first_model.merged_models.build] do |ff| %>
```

But got:

> no implicit conversion of MergedModel into Integer

Not completely understand what that means..

Also tried creating a new MergedModel from a FirstModel's create action, with a bang:

```
@merge_model = MergedModel.create!
```

And got the same error - no implicit conversion...

Could anyone explain more about this? I feel its about passing an Array of my MergedModel's params into MergedModel's params...? I am totally lost here...

Comment: Your form should have `fields_for :merged_models` instead of just `merged_model`

Comment: I'm glad it worked. We've all been there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form should have `fields_for :merged_models` instead of just `merged_model`.

Answer (score 1):

On fresh installs of Rails5 applications, `belongs_to` implies `optional: false` by default (previously called `required: true`).

You need to create a `MergedModel` both with `FirstModel` AND `SecondModel` associated...

It looks like you are trying create a `MergedModel` only with a `FirstModel` associated, if `SecondModel` is optional, you need to say that for `belongs_to` with...

```
belongs_to :second_model, optional: true
```

Comment: sorry pal, I forgot to rewrite that I already added that to MergedModel (not because I knew about this change in Rails5, but because I really needed that optional:true functionality)